# Yeoman looping in template

Tags: javascript, typescript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to use yeoman to take this JSON file:

```
{
  "models": {
    "user": {
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "surname": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": "number"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And turn it into something like:

```
Class User {
  name : string
  surname : string
  id : number
}
```

Would it be possible to do some form of looping in the template? Here's what I have in mind...

```
  export class <%= entityName %> extends Model   {
      <% forEach (property in props) { %>
         <%= property.name %> : <% property.type %>;
      <% } %>
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The template language can run any JS code. So just use normal `for` loop or iterations methods on arrays (`arr.forEach()`)

```
export class <%= entityName %> extends Model   {
    <% for (property of props) { %>
         <%= property.name %> : <% property.type %>;
    <% } %>
}
```

Yeoman is using [ejs](http://ejs.co/) as template engine. Visit their website for more [information on the supported features](http://ejs.co/).

Answer (score -2):

I dont think you can use that kind of looping in the template. What you could do is to have a helpermethod in your script file to generate the content from your json file into a variable, and then add that variable to your template.